# Less verbose OR condition in cypher

Tags: neo4j, nlp, cypher

In neo4j, I want to fetch all noun or proper noun related by a certain relationship. I've got a query like this

```
match (n)-[r]->(n1) where n:NOUN and n1:NOUN or n:NOUN and n1:PROPN or n:PROPN and n1:NOUN or n1:PROPN and n:PROPN return r
```

Is there something more compact to do it? Like:

```
match (n:[NOUN, PROPN])-[r]->(n1:[NOUN, PROPN]) return r
```

Answer (score 2):

There's no such syntax for node labels, it's only available for relationship types.

Instead, why not improve your model?

You could use a second, common label: common nouns and proper nouns are all nouns, so why not use the `NOUN` label for everyone, specializing them with an additional label like `PROPN` or `COMMN`.

1. Mark all (current) nouns as common nouns:

   ```
   MATCH (n:NOUN) SET n:COMMN
   ```
2. Mark all proper nouns as nouns:

   ```
   MATCH (n:PROPN) SET n:NOUN
   ```
3. Your query is then simply:

   ```
   MATCH (n:NOUN)-[r]->(n1:NOUN) return r
   ```